# Adding text to a variable on the Authorization header visual studio 2013 load test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I am creating some load tests in visual studio 2013.

The test has 2 steps

1. authentication:  This method returns a token that I need to call the second method, I am getting the value using an extraction rule and I am putting it on a variable called token
2. list:  This method returns a list of items that belongs to the user authenticated and I need to send in the header on the authorization value: Bearer token

I have the token but I need to add before that the text: Bearer

I have not been able to concatenate anything through the interface.  I tried generating the test code and adding it there but when it runs it doesn't pick up the code, but the configuration done on the interface

Answer (score 1):

I found how yay!  well I am new at this tool but I forund that instead of selection the variable I can write {{token}} and I can put more variables there and text if needed